# Yii2 DateRangePicker default value does not work

Tags: php, yii2

I am using [kartik date-range](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-date-range) in order to select date range in my yii2 app, but after trying some ways i could not set default value to date range picker, please see my codes :

```
<?php  echo $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(DateRangePicker::className(), [
    'value'=> '2016-05-17 00:00:00',
    'convertFormat'=>true,
    'pluginOptions'=>[
        'timePicker'=>true,
        'timePickerIncrement'=>15,
        'locale'=>['format'=>'Y-m-d H:i:s']
    ]
])
?>
```

date input box does not show default value and it is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because your $model->date is being used as default with widget so for that if it is empty you can assign the value directly before creating field

```
$model->date = '2016-05-17 00:00:00';
```